# Search-Everywhere in Android Studio (IntelliJ) makes Search File redundant?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio (and IntelliJ), `shift-shift` is used to Search File (and Everywhere, e.g. class name etc).

I just realize it also have `shift-command-O` that search for a file.

With `shift-shift`, it seems to me `shift-command-O` is redundant.

So I'm checking to see if I have miss something that is in `shift-command-O` but not in `shift-shift`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift-Shift shows a popup with occurrences of the string you've entered in names of files, classes, symbols and actions. Shift-Command-O shows a popup with occurrences of the same string only in names of files. Same task, same UI (in recent IJ/AS versions) more narrow filter.

Answer (score -1):

Well you're almost right but there is one main difference in those two commands.

Shift shift will search for a file.
While shift-command-o will go to the specified file.

I guess in a way they to de same, but if you use Shift-command-o you will be redirected to that file and saves you one click.
But feel free to use what you want, shortcuts are for convenience so you should use what is most comfortable.

Here is a link with all shortcuts in IntelliJ IDEA, could be usefull in the future :)

https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "will search" and "will goto". Both popups require you to press Enter or click on a result to navigate to it. The number of clicks is exactly the same.